# JQuery UI sortables / draggable clone not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sortables

Hi folks am using UI fro some drag  drop, problem is that I cannot get the "clone" to fire.

I have 2 `<ul><li></li></ul>` lists and I want to drag from list 1 to list 2 OK that bit is easy, but getting the "clone" to remain in list one is not.  What I need / want to happen is drag from list 1 to list 2 (one way drag only), then on receive in list 2 hide remove the dragged item - OK sounds strange but the ID of the dragged item loads a page based on that ID into the created "empty" `<li>` in the 2nd `<ul>`

So far "we" looking something like this:

```
 $('ul#inputs_menu li ul').sortable({

connectWith: "ul#layout_form",

}).disableSelection();

$('ul#inputs_menu li ul li').sortable({

helper: "clone"

}).disableSelection();


$(' ul#layout_form' ).sortable({

receive: function(event, ui) {

var new_item = (ui.item).attr('id');

$('ul#layout_form').append('<li><div id="'+new_item.substr(4)+'"class="'+new_item.substr(4)+' inputs radius_10" ></div></li>');

$('#'+new_item.substr(4)).load('includes/text.php?fld_name='+new_item.substr(4));

}

}).disableSelection();
```

Suggestions please - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ui.item` which is the original, you want `ui.helper` here, which is the clone.  Also, you can cut down on overall code and selector work by using [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) instead, like this:

```
$('#inputs_menu li ul').sortable({
  connectWith: "ul#layout_form",
}).disableSelection();
$('#inputs_menu li ul li').sortable({
  helper: "clone"
}).disableSelection();

$('#layout_form' ).sortable({
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    var new_item = ui.helper.id.substr(4);
    $('<li><div id="'+new_item+'"class="'+new_item+' inputs radius_10" ></div></li>')
      .appendTo('#layout_form')
      .find("div").load('includes/text.php?fld_name='+new_item);            
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, tried that but even that didn't get me the ID or Class of the clone AND the orginal/clone dissapears

Comment: @rmap - Are you duplicating the ID?  Test the updated version which doesn't rely on it as a selector...if you're ending up with duplicated IDs then that's your issue, and you need to make them unique (or don't use them on the new element, they can simply be removed in my version above).

Comment: Again thanks Nick, but sadly no joy, what I find strange is that if I try to use helper: clone in #inputs_menu li ul nothing, but if I "redeclare" #inputs_menu li ul li as a sortable then it seems to work (i.i. the clone)

Comment: @rmap - The original definitely shouldn't be dissapearing with the method above, since we're creating a new element, do you have an example page with your markup?

Comment: Nick I have simplified the page like this: LIST ONE
<ul id="inputs_menu" class="fb_clearfix"><li><a href="#">Header 1</a><ul><?php for($x=0; $x<=5; $x++): ?><li id="str_<?php echo $x; ?>"><img src="images/icons/<?php echo $x; ?>.png" width="16px" height="16px" alt="Input type icon" /><?php echo $x; ?></li>
<?php endfor; ?></ul></li></ul>LIST TWO<ul class="radius_10 inner_white" id="layout_form"></ul>

Comment: NOTE List 2 in empty untill the first item is dragged.  On arrival in "list 2" what should happen is the "dragged" li content is "removed" and replaced as I have said with a page e.g. str_$x.php.  But what needs to happen is the item remains in list 1 so it can be re-used.

Comment: @rmap - Try this code, made a few adjustments: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gDFCH/ i'll take a look at the clone piece, that's a draggable option though, one minute

Comment: @rmap - I think this is what you're after: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gDFCH/1/ making the original draggables (where `clone` functions properly), see if it works for your needs.

Comment: Nick, thanks. Was getting there myself, just one quick q how can I remove/hide the clone once it gets to list2 and the page loads?

Comment: @rmap - The second argument to `.load("url", [data], [callback])` can be a function, like this `.load("includes..", function() { $(this).remove(); })` would remove the `<div>` when it loaded, `.parent().remove()` for the `<li>`, etc...is what what you're after?

Comment: Nick, may not be the "prettiest) but this works a treat now. thanks a lot